# Datepicker returning uncaught typeError: undefined 'currentDay'

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've been using jQuery UI with Bootstrap and I seem to run into a problem that I haven't had before. I'm not sure what has changed; I've tried setting back different version of jQuery and I didn't update the jQuery UI in the meanwhile. So I'm not exactly sure what broke.

The error from the console when I click on any date in the datepicker returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined
```

The code is fairly straightforward as one would expect from a datepicker:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

With the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

Is this a bug that should be reported (since no other Google matches turn up) or is it something else I've missed?

Comment: I think there may be some conflict with jQuery UI's datepicker and boostrap's datepicker, I suggest you choose one and remove the other from the js files.

Comment: Good call, but unfortunately I'm only using Bootstrap CSS with jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery-UI 1.9.2. I'm not using Bootstrap-UI at this time.

Comment: i found the the error goes if use #ID and not .class

Comment: @BjornSchijff I am getting this problem only when using **[Datatable](https://datatables.net)**. In normal HTML page, datepicker works awesome.

Comment: Probably means your Datatable is reusing your datepicker, which needs to have a unique ID.

Comment: Unique ID was a great clue, in my case im in a razor shared template that is used twice -- having an ID repeated caused the issue. Thanks to Bjorn & Harpreet I was able to solve a similiar problem. If you are having this error look for any non-unique id if id is specified, doesn't have to be datatables or bootstrap-jqueryUI conflict related.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I've found the solution. After a long time of debugging I figured out that there was a `<div>` that had the exact same `ID`, lying higher than the input field. Therefore the script took the first instance that contained the `ID` and picked the `DIV` instead of the `input` field.

I removed/renamed the `DIV` and it worked fine again.

Comment: Sometimes it's very useful to put your page in an HTML validator! :)

Comment: thank you very much it's work 100% but i change the <input type="text" id="CheckOut" name="CheckOut2" ---- name attribute

Comment: been 2 hours on this bug, finally found your solution <3

Comment: Thank you Bjorn!  This totally worked.  In my case it was a label with the same id.

Answer (score 21):

The above jQuery datepicker error is generally caused by having a duplicate controls with the same ID, no matter whether you use id or another selector like css class or field name to instantiate it.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Don't use IDs ever with datepicker, use custom css class names. I was facing that problem when using datepicker inside popover.

Comment: @tod-birdsall & others,  I have the same issue linked here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883482/datatable-datefilter-loads-correctly-but-throws-uncaught-typeerror-on-date-selec   I tried many solutions like different id, classes etc. No matter, the issue pops up even in 2017 4 years after this original thread.  Is it a bug with datatable or jquery UI?  Strangely, if I tried to create name attribute in input control, it gets duplicated in page one more time. The error inevitably occurs. Is there any solid solution to this problem.  I am using latest version of datatable and jquery UI.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with create new  ID for HTML DOM object. There is duplicated Id.
Try to add new ID for HTML DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error also. I found that elsewhere on the form I had some label 'for' attributes that did not match ids on the form inputs - seems like this might confuse datepicker too. Once I fixed those up, everything worked fine and the error went away. Take Andreas' advice (+1 for that!) and validate your forms - Chris Pederick's Web Developer Toolbar gives you an easy way to validate as you go.

Answer (score 1):

put a selector.

```
<script>  $("#formID #duplicatedId").datepicker({language: 'he'});
</script>
```

FormID: Id of the form that contains input.

duplicatedId: input element's Id.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was triggering the datepicker from a div against a hidden input field and getPos(a) was causing an undefined message on the variable "a".  I experimented with moving the hidden input field outside of a div and that did the trick.  Note that the input field was findable by jQuery no matter where it was, so that was not the problem - it was with positioning.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Might be two input box having same class without different id and for that you are trying for date picker. If it is there give two different id it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem too, and i was 100% sure i did not use duplicate id.
After some debugging i found out a reason - i was using DataTables mod, which duplicates contents of tfoot, thus creating exact copy of datepicker elements. And i had this datepicker inputs in tfoot row.

Fixed that issue with:

```
table.find("TFOOT").find("TR:first").remove();
```

Which is called AFTER table.DataTable(....)

This removed original, zero height row with all contents;