# ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I cannot select/click dates on my datepciker and when I'm doing that it always create an error. I've already check id's in my page but doesn't have any duplicate. I put input at a modal from.

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



$('#reschedule-txt').datepicker({

   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

   changeMonth: true,

   changeYear: true

});

Reschedule Interview:

<input type="text" id="reschedule-txt" name="reschedule" class="extendexpirationdate-design"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datepicker returning uncaught typeError: undefined 'currentDay'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781425/datepicker-returning-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-currentday)